# How to search for detectors by tags in splunk sfx?

Tags: terraform, splunk, signalfx

I'm using terraform to maintain our sfx dashboards and detectors. I added tags to the detectors so that we can search by the tags, but when I go into the sfx UI I don't see an option for searching by tags. Is that not possible? Why else have tags on the detectors?

I tried looking at the filter and I see what looks like a tag but when I change it to my tag the dimension is "sf_tags" and if I change it to my tag nothing comes up.

Comment: Please take a look here first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.